# How can I make a decreasing delay?

Tags: assembly, delay

I want to make a subroutine in assembly that will be a decreasing delay, for example:

- the first time will be a delay of 1 sec
- the next time 700 ms
- until 0 secs

Comment: What architecture - x86? arm?  what do you mean by delay?  what do you expect to happen in between the delays?  should it print something?  so what platform - windows, osx, linux.  By delay do you mean the program should still be scheduled on the CPU or should it yield to other processes for this time?

Comment: by delay i mean that i want the program execute some commands so that will delay the next command.

Comment: architecture is x86 . by delay i mean "execute dump" for some time. for example   mov ax,00   start:  inc ax  cmp ax,10  jne start  int3(end)

Answer (score 0):

Write a delay subroutine which takes a delay value as a parameter. Then in the loop that calls the delay subroutine you can take care of decrementing the delay value. In C this might look something like this:

```
void delay(int t)
{
    // ... code here to generate delay of t ms ...
} 

// ...

for (delay_time = 1000; delay_time >= 0; delay_time -= 300) // delay = 1000, 700, 400, 100 ms
{
    // ... do stuff ...

    if (delay > 0) delay(delay_time);
}
```

Now all you need to do is take this general structure and translate it to asm for whatever CPU you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

since now i use something like this:

- mov al,0Ah
- mov bl,0Ah
- start:
- dec al
- cmp al,00h
- jne start
- mov al,0Ah
- dec bl
- cmp bl,00h
- jne start
- HLT

but this is a steady loop, i want this to be decreased every time is executed, i know i must interact with an external register/memory.

Answer (score 0):

since different CPUs run at different speeds, you should use a slightly different routine.. the CPU keeps a timer at memory location 40:6ch, as written on randall hyde's book the art of assembly language:

> For now, we will simply take
>   advantage of the fact that this timer chip forces the CPU to increment a 32-bit memory
>   location (40:6ch) about 18.2 times per second. By looking at this variable we can determine
>   the speed of the CPU and adjust the count value for an empty loop accordingly.
>
> The basic idea of the following code is to watch the BIOS timer variable until it
>   changes. Once it changes, start counting the number of iterations through some sort of
>   loop until the BIOS timer variable changes again. Having noted the number of iterations,
>   if you execute a similar loop the same number of times it should require about 1/18.2 sec-
>   onds to execute.

This is Paul R's delay routine.

---

Then you could make a procedure like the one you're already using, but which takes the delay in ax (I assume you're working only with 16 bits register, right?). Try using ah instead of bl, so that you can subtract, let's say, 0400h from ax before calling this procedure:

```
        mov      ax, ffffh       ; probably you'll need to tune this value
```

a:      ; your printing code
        sub      ax, 0400h       ; and this one too
        push     ax              ; it needs to be saved because
        call     delay           ; delay resets it
        pop      ax
;       ...      ...
        j??      a
main    endp
proc    delay
        push     bx              ; save bx's contents
        mov      bl, al          ; and a copy of al
l1:     dec      al              ; loop until al > 0
; here you can add some delaying instructions, like scanning
; quite long strings with repne scasb
        jnz      l1
        mov      al, bl          ; restore al's original value
        dec      ah              ; decrease ah
        jnz      l1              ; and loop until > 0
        pop      bx
        ret
delay   endp

If I understood your problem this should work well..

Comment: actually i don't mind so much the exact time. i am working on a project that display chars on seven segments. so it's more like how it looks(eye speed). my main problem is to make a delay every time my print routine works so  to make an effect that my string will be blinking on increasing(decreasing) speed.

Comment: i think this should work. thanx a lot. i need to study that now :P